# Filtrar Dados para base de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, sqlite

Boa tarde,

Tenho um problema que espero que alguém me possa ajudar. Necessitava de passar cerca de 700 entradas para uma base de dados (neste caso SQLite Studio) mas não consigo arranjar uma maneira de filtrar essas 700 entradas sem ser manualmente. Tem aqui um exemplo: Araújo, A.; Fernandes, L. e Oliveira, T. (2000). Linguagem C. Edições Atlas. Lisboa. ISBN 990-888-567-231-5. Necessito de obter este tipo de entrada dividida por colunas numa tabela pelas categorias corretas tais como autores, anos, etc. Há alguma maneira de introduzir estas 700 entradas sem ser manualmente? Foi me falado de programas que liam o html e podiam filtrar os dados, mas ainda não consegui encontrar nada. Se alguém com mais conhecimento nisto me conseguisse ajudar agradecia imenso.

Comment: Você precisa achar um caractere que defina a quebra da parte. Parece que o ponto seguido de espaço tem essa função. O problema é que se tiver algum texto com o mesmo padrão quebrará em parte onde é uma coisa só. De qualquer forma, a pergunta está formulada de um jeito que ficará difícil ajudar mais do que este comentário.

Comment: Poste alguns exemplos e como você gostaria que ficasse. Essa relação é possivel baixar da internet?

Comment: Eu tentaria importar no excel (Aba dados -> de texto). Define o ponto seguido de espaço como delimitador. Veja se ele separa as colunas corretamente. Se der certo, depois exporta do excel para o banco de dados.